# Aireplay issues

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I started using the aircrack-suite and to be more specific it is about aireplay-ng. The problem ist that...

```
aireplay-ng -0 wlan0mon
```

...does work, but...

```
aireplay-ng -9 wlan0mon
```

...doesn't

In fact the ath10k driver is used and I know packet injection isn't working for that driver but why is the first command working?

**UPDATE**
Because of requests what the error messages or unexpected behavior is:
I currently can't use my laptop but I can describe it more specific

```
aireplay-ng -0
```

Can do what it is supposed to do: I deauths my phone (for example). But what does not work is the injection test: yes it can find APs but doesn't get any ARP replies... Now my question is why does deauth work and the injection test does not?

Comment: Welcome to Security SE! What do you mean it doesn't work? Does the program error out? Please add more details.

Comment: "does not work" means very little. What does not work? What are the error messages, or unexpected behavior?